# not to display empty results in php from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
+------------------+
| Tables_employees |
+------------------+
| empid            | 
| aid              | 
| FirstName        | 
| LastName         | 
| Email            |
| Phone            |

<table id="exampleC" class="display" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="" style="font-size:small;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1st Name</th> 
            <th>2nd Name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone(D)</th>
            <th>Linkedin</th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        require_once 'tabconnect.php';
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $data = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT acquisition.aid,acquisition.aby,employees.empid,employees.aid,employees.FirstName,employees.LastName,employees.title,employees.email,employees.phone,employees.dphone,employees.LIUrl,employees.listatus FROM employees JOIN acquisition ON acquisition.aid=employees.aid where acquisition.aid=$id");

                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { ?>  
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row3['FirstName']; </td>
                <td><?php echo $row3['LastName']; ?</td>
                <td><?php echo $row3['title']; ?></td>
                <td><a class="" href="<?php echo $row3['email']; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa fa-envelope"></i></td>                                       
                <td><a class="" href="<?php echo $row3['phone']; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa-phone"></i></td>                                     
            </tr>                     
        <?php
                }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is that it will display all the email and phone images, but I want to display images only when there will be a records in table

Comment: You need to read up on sql injection.

Comment: It would be nice to see some sample table data along with what you actually want to show from that in PHP.

Comment: Your question it not clear on what you want. Your last line you want to display images only if there's image data or you want display other data only if there's images ?

Comment: Do you want to skip the whole record or just the icons if the values are null?

Comment: Display icons when there will be records in table otherwise icons will not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear that you want to fill all the records or only record which have icons, you can check the fields like below:

```
<?php
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
  ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><a class="" href="<?php echo ($row3['email'])?$row3['email']:''; ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php if($row3['email']!=''){ echo '<i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa fa-envelope"></i>';
            }else{echo '';} ?></td>                                       
        <td><a class="" href="<?php echo ($row3['phone'])?$row3['phone']:''; ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php if($row3['email']!=''){ echo '<i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa-phone"></i>'; }
            else{echo '';}</td>                                     
    </tr>                     
 <?php 
        } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Display icons when there will be records in table otherwise icons will not display

Comment: Now check my answer

Comment: It works.Thank you very much.Just another query, when I click LI icon there is a message "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8" How I will overcome it

Comment: I am not understand properly. Give your html and php code in another question.

Comment: <td><a class="" href="<?php echo ($row3['LIUrl'])?$row3['LIUrl']:''; ?>" target="_blank">
                     <?php if($row3['LIUrl']!=''){ echo '<i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa fa-linkedin"></i>';
                     }else{echo '';} ?></td> 
and Linkedin field is "http:'//www.linkedin.com/in/jeffrey-anderson-4725b811" 
I want to display Linkedn page in another tab when I click LI Icons

Comment: change this line  :

Comment: href="<?php echo empty($row3['LIUrl']) ? "" : $row3['LIUrl']; ?>"

Comment: it means it empty and no link in it

Comment: it works.Thank you very much.Ignore my previous comments.How to accept your answers?

Comment: glad to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($row3['email'] && $row3['phone']) { ?>

 <td><a class="" href="<?php echo $row3['email']; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa fa-envelope"></i></td>                                       
 <td><a class="" href="<?php echo $row3['phone']; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-custom icon-sm rounded-x fa fa-phone"></i></td>  


<?php } ?>
```

Check if phone and email are not null and then display the phone and email icons.